# Best way to show error message for image upload in rich text editor?

Tags: error-message, feedback, image, text-editor

Any good examples of sites/apps that solve this in an elegant way?

I would like to show the error message in close proximity of the image upload button.

Note: not the **attachment** link/button, but the add image inline in the editor button at the top of the editor.
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: All text editors I know work with a dialog, modal, or, less commonly, a hidden div for images (see this site for an example of the latter). So, the error will be in that element, not in the action button or close to it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to show error messages for image upload is to show an image upload progress indicator. An error message is helpful once something has gone wrong, but if a user has chosen a ridiculously large image or has restricted upload speeds they will require Visibility of System Status.

Here's an example of a progress indicator modal being used with TinyMCE. An advantage of using a modal instead of notification in the rich text editor is it will also signify to the user that they shouldn't attempt other actions or navigate from the page.

[image]